# JavaScript code to display icons in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this script which is supposed to display these 7 icons in a loop. I want it to look like a phone is being charged, but it doesn't work. How can I add the last icon (**assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_full_48px.svg**) into the loop.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var icons = [2,3,5,6,8,9];

        function displayIcons() {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
                show(i);
            }
        }
        function show(i) {

            setTimeout(function() {

                    $('div span').html('<img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_'+ icons[i] + '0_48px.svg">');

            }, 1000 + i * 1000);

        }

            displayIcons();

    });
```

These are the icons.

```
<div class="container2">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_20_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_30_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_50_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_60_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_80_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_90_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_full_48px.svg">
</div>
```

[image: icons]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Why not use a GIF file?

Comment: Do you need this to be in setTimeout? and should show them with delay?

Comment: insted use `setInterval()`

Comment: @Giri I need to use JavaScript and I know it is possible.

Comment: And what exactly isn't working

Comment: @adeneo I don't know how to fix _full_48px.svg icon at the end of a single loop

Comment: So all the images are changing, you just don't know how to add the last one? You should probably lead with that in the question !

Comment: @adeneo Now that you've understood my question, how I can go about achieving that?

Comment: Why not just change the name of the file to `assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_100_48px.svg` and add `10` in the icons array?

Comment: @JonathanCrowe Whaaaat! You are a genius

Comment: I'd take a more resource-friendly approach and use a sprint, set it as background an animate its position so that only the relevant part is shown. Decreases load time and prevents flickering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the last one to the array, like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var icons = [20, 30, 50, 60, 80, 90, 'full'];

    function displayIcons() {
        for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
            show(i);
        }
    }

    function show(i) {

        setTimeout(function () {

            $('div span').html('<img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_' + icons[i] + '_48px.svg">');

        }, 1000 + i * 1000);

    }

    displayIcons();
});
```

Comment: I want to display one icon at a time. Hence I must overwrite the previous displayed icon.

Comment: So you don't want it like the image you've provided, you want to change the same image to a new one? In that case it seems to work fine ?

Comment: This scripts works but one last thing. I want to display the icons in a loop (i.e after the last icon is displayed, it should go back to the first icon).... and then do this for 5mins

Comment: @Richie - something like this should do that -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/tcm4f9gd/1/**

Comment: One last thing. I have an battery_fully_charged icon. How do I display it, say, after 10 mins.... obviously after stopping the charging loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. In your case, you may use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`

```
var icons = [2,3,5,6,8,9];
var iconsLength = icons.length;
var i=0;
function displayIcons() {
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){
        if(i < iconsLength){
            $('div span').html('<img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_'+ icons[i] + '0_48px.svg">');
            i++;
        }else{
            $('div span').html('<img src="assets/iconsic_battery_charging_full_48px.svg">'); //For your last image which is not in your array list
            clearInterval(myVar);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
displayIcons();
```

Comment: @Asik It lacks the timer. It should display one icon at a time, not all at once.

Answer (score 1):

You more likely want something like this (not tested)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tId=setInterval(function() {
    var $imgs $(".charging");
    var $active = $(".active");
    if ($active.length==0) $imgs.first().addClass("active").show();
    else {
      if ($active.next().length=0) {
        clearInterval(tId);
      }
      else {
        $active.removeClass("active).hide();
        $next.addClass("active").show();                    
      }                          
    }
  },500);
});
```

```css
.charging { display:none }
```

```html
<div class="container2">
        <img class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_20_48px.svg">
        <img class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_30_48px.svg">
        <img class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_50_48px.svg">
        <img class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_60_48px.svg">
        <img class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_80_48px.svg">
        <img class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_90_48px.svg">
        <img class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_full_48px.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution.  It's a bit different but better because thanks to the use of CSS, it is both semantic and accessible.  The 'Charging...' text is readable by screen readers, and no unnecessary HTML images are added.  You can of course change the text to whatever you want.

CSS:

```
#chargingbox {
    width: 20px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_20_48px.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chargingbox">Charging...</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var delay = 100, // in ms, change to whatever you want
        current_icon_index = 0,
        icon_urls = [
            'assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_20_48px.svg',
            'assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_30_48px.svg',
            'assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_50_48px.svg',
            'assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_60_48px.svg',
            'assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_80_48px.svg',
            'assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_90_48px.svg',
            'assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_full_48px.svg'
        ];


    var step_through = function() {
        $('#chargingbox').css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + icon_urls[current_icon_index] +')'
        });
        current_icon_index++;
        if (current_icon_index === icon_urls.length-1) {
            current_icon_index = 0;
        }
        setTimeout(step_through, delay);
    };

    step_through();

});
```

Comment: This is working but I think _full_ icon is not being displayed.

Comment: change the CSS to edit the width for the width, and padding-top for the height of the icon.

Comment: I have changed width:200px to display a full icon. 20px cuts the icon into half

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This works as you requested. Its best to load all image in the dom and not appending as we want. That may cause load delays if its on a network.

JQuery:
    $(document).ready(function(){

```
        function displayIcons() {
            var target = $('.container2 img');
            var targetTotal = target.length;
            var i=0;
            target.hide().eq(0).show();

            setInterval(function(){

                target.hide().eq(i).show();
                if(i == targetTotal-1){
                    i=0;
                } else {
                    i=i+1;
                }

            },1000);
        }

        displayIcons();

    });
```

HTML: as you already had

```
<div class="container2">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_20_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_30_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_50_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_60_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_80_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_90_48px.svg">
        <img src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_full_48px.svg">
</div>
```

I've used 'ul li'  to play in this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nbwm2Lxo/

Answer (score 0):

I am writing here simple code, try this, in this i used id for getting image location,i used same id used for array. I tried simple solution for this, may it will help you to understand, and you can easily modify it.

```js
var icons = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
$(document).ready(function(){
            displayIcons();
    });
function callShowHide(i)
{
    $(".charging").hide();
    $("#"+i).show();
  if(i == icons.length)
    {  
       displayIcons();
    }
}

function displayIcons() {
   var i;
   for (i = 1; i <= icons.length; i++) {
     show(i);
     }
   }

function show(i) {
   setTimeout("callShowHide('"+i+"')",1000 + i * 1000);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
        <img id="1" alt="1" class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_20_48px.svg">
        <img  id="2" alt="2"   class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_30_48px.svg">
        <img  id="3"  alt="3" class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_50_48px.svg">
        <img id="4"   alt="4" class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_60_48px.svg">
        <img  id="5" alt="5"  class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_c alt="1" harging_80_48px.svg">
        <img id="6"  alt="6" class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_90_48px.svg">
        <img  id="7"  alt="7" class="charging" src="assets/icons/ic_battery_charging_full_48px.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this   http://dabblet.com/gist/ea6aa5771b8b777d7bc6

```css
/**
 * stackoverflow.com/questions/26943273/javascript-code-to-display-icons-in-a-loop#26943449
 */
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
:root,body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center
}

.charging{
 width: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 40px auto;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #b3b3b3;
    -webkit-animation: charging 3s infinite;
 animation: charging 3s infinite
}

.charging:before, .charging:after{
 position: absolute;
 width: 0; 
 height: 0;
 content: ""
}

.charging:before{
 top: 20px;
 left: 7px;
 border-left: 2px solid transparent;
 border-right:6px solid transparent;
 border-top: 12px solid #ffffff;
}

.charging:after{
 top: 12px;
 left: 3px;
 border-left: 6px solid transparent;
 border-right:2px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 12px solid #ffffff;
 
}
@-webkit-keyframes charging {
   0%{
  box-shadow: inset 0  -4px  0 #000000
   }
   20%{
     box-shadow: inset 0  -12px  0 #000000
   }
   40%{
     box-shadow: inset 0  -20px  0 #000000
   }
   60%{
     box-shadow: inset 0  -28px  0 #000000
   }
   80%{
     box-shadow: inset 0  -60px  0 #000000
   }
   100%{
     box-shadow: inset 0  0px  0 #b3b3b3
   }
}

@keyframes charging {
   0%{
  box-shadow: inset 0  -4px  0 #000000
   }
   20%{
     box-shadow: inset 0  -12px  0 #000000
   }
   40%{
     box-shadow: inset 0  -20px  0 #000000
   }
   60%{
     box-shadow: inset 0  -28px  0 #000000
   }
   80%{
     box-shadow: inset 0  -60px  0 #000000
   }
   100%{
     box-shadow: inset 0  0px  0 #b3b3b3
   }
}
```

```html
<div class=charging></div>
```